# uTorrent limit upload speed

Tags: download, speed

I almost cannot browse a thing when I'm downloading anything off uTorrent and I think it's because of the constant high upload speed because it uploads at the maximum capacity of my network.

Is there anyway I can just stop uploading without limiting my downloading speed at all?

Comment: @Ramhound actually that is not true. The main problem is most SOHO routers can not handle having its upload at 100% usage and will start dropping packets. This causes the ACK packets in a TCP connection to never get back to the server and you get slow browsing. Limiting your upload to about 75% fixes it, and utorrent has a speed test feature built in that will set that for you.

Comment: I have tried limiting that and it worked fine at a time. But I don't know since the newer versions of the software, limiting upload speed automatically limits the download speed too. How can we set it so as the download speed is not affected?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/263904/fixing-bufferbloat-in-home-network

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to limit uploading completely.

Most modern torrenting clients provide a cap for your upload speed. uTorrent is no different. You can click on the "U: *current speed*" portion of the GUI in the bottom right side of the client with a right click, and then select your desired speed. For example, if your maximum upload speed is 100 kb/s, you could limit it to 50 or 70 kb/s. Experiment, and see what works best for you.

[image]

It's enough to cap the upload to 50-70% (this is based on personal experience, you might even set it to 80 or 90%, but I haven't experimented that much) of your total upload speed. That will allow for no distractions while browsing the internet, downloading other things, etc.

Please do not turn off your upload, as you damage the torrent community that way. For example, if you're trying to download a Linux distro (let's say Ubuntu) over a torrent, then you depend on all the people that have already downloaded that file to share it with you. If everyone would just download, and then stop uploading - torrents would die, and no one would be able to download files over torrents anymore.

Bottom line, you can still seed (upload) and browse/download whatever at the same time. Just decrease the maximum speed at which you are uploading to something less than 100% of your upload speed.

Comment: I have tried limiting that and it worked fine at a time. But I don't know since the newer versions of the software, limiting upload speed automatically limits the download speed too. How can we set it so as the download speed is not affected?

Comment: I am not sure. I would probably go with an older version, 'cause I find it better than the newest one, anyway.

There might not even be a way. I don't have the new client, so I can't help you out there. Sorry.